# Выбор языка и GUI для кроссплатформенного приложения

Tags: windows, gui, mac, linux

Добрый день. Мне надо написать десктоп приложение для винды, мака и линукс. Какой язык мне выбрать и GUI для минимизации затрат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Языков много. Смотря какое приложение пишите, какие у него требования. Можно попробовать Python. Если гуй несложный, можно писать на Tk/Tcl, модуль для работы с ним входит в батарейки. Если хочется чего-то более приличного и серьезного, то PyQt. Последний вариант - самое лучшее сочетание мощности и переносимости.

Если большие требования по скорости и т.п., то С++ + Qt.

Answer (score 4):

Модуль TK/TcL для python называется Tkinter, сам писал на нём. Но мой выбор с недавнего времени для такого рода занятий это C++

Answer (score 2):

Если приложение это достаточно простая форма на экране и дальше идет тоже простая обработка на основе заполненных полей, то посмотрите на Tcl/Tk.